# Setting the stacksize of the threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I was trying a simple program to set the attribute - stacksize of the threads.
But with the below codes output I see that the stacksize is not changed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define NUMTHREADS 5

pthread_attr_t myattr;

void* mythread(void* arg){
        size_t stacksize;

        pthread_attr_getstacksize(&myattr,&stacksize);

        printf("\n tid : %u : %d stacksize : %d \n",(unsigned int)pthread_self(),(int)arg,stacksize);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
        int i = 0;
        pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];
        pthread_attr_t myattr;
        size_t stacksize;

        /*Initialse and set thread detach attribute */
        pthread_attr_init(&myattr);
//      pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&myattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
        pthread_attr_getstacksize(&myattr,&stacksize);
        printf("\n Initial Stack size : %d \n",stacksize);

        stacksize = stacksize + 100;

        pthread_attr_setstacksize(&myattr,stacksize);

        //pthread_attr_destroy(&myattr);

        for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++){
                printf("\n Creating Threads! \n");
                pthread_create(&threads[i],&myattr,&mythread,(void*)i);
        }

#if 1
        for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++){
                printf("\n Joining Threads! \n");
                pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
        }
#endif

        pthread_attr_getstacksize(&myattr,&stacksize);
        printf("\n Initial Stack size : %d \n",stacksize);

        printf("\n Main tid : %u \n",(unsigned int)pthread_self());
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Output :

angus@ubuntu:~/angus/thread$ ./a.out

Initial Stack size : 8388608

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Joining Threads!

tid : 2443623808 : 4 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 2443726208 : 3 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 2443828608 : 2 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 2443931008 : 1 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 2444033408 : 0 stacksize : 8388608

Joining Threads!

Joining Threads!

Joining Threads!

Joining Threads!

Main tid : 2444044032

**EDITED :**  **O/P after the edit by commenting pthread_attr_destroy() based on "R's" answer**

angus@ubuntu:~/angus/thread$ ./a.out

Initial Stack size : 8388608

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Creating Threads!

Joining Threads!

tid : 855779136 : 4 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 864171840 : 3 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 872564544 : 2 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 880957248 : 1 stacksize : 8388608

tid : 889349952 : 0 stacksize : 8388608

Joining Threads!

Joining Threads!

Joining Threads!

Joining Threads!

Initial Stack size : 8388708

Main tid : 897656576

Comment: Your edit (trying to comment out the `pthread_attr_destroy`) broke the formatting and potentially changed the question. Please don't make edits like this based on answers unless you're going to add text to the question explaining that the behavior remains the same with the program changed.

Comment: Sorry R. Would take care the same while editing questions based on the answers

Answer (score 1):

You're using an attribute object after destroying it, so the behavior is undefined. Remove this line or move it after the thread creation:

```
    pthread_attr_destroy(&myattr);
```

Comment: Thanks R. The stacksize of the main thread has been modified but the threads created from the main. How to set the stack size of the threads created. I read that pthread_attr_setstacksize() does it. But from the exercise I see the main threads stack has been modified to the value

Comment: How do you think your code is measuring the stack size of the main thread or the newly created threads? It's not, and in fact there's no standard way to measure it. All you're doing is re-printing what you set in the attribute object. You need to either trust that the attribute is being honored if you code is valid, or use a nonstandard function like `pthread_getattr_np` (if supported on your system) to get a running thread's attributes, or use an external memory use monitoring tool to observe the amount of memory used.

Comment: Also, you have two different objects called `myattr`. One is local to main and the other is global. This is probably part of your confusion.

Comment: This hadn't actually answered his question, just pointed an errror (correction of which hadn't changed result, of rather lack of it.).

Comment: @brainovergrow: Indeed, I didn't realize immediately how much was wrong with OP's program. Your answer is better, but this answer still has useful content in the answer and comments so I don't really want to delete it..

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to measure stack size, however error prone.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUMTHREADS 2

pthread_attr_t myattr;


void* mythread(void* arg){
        char stack_start = (char) (unsigned int)pthread_self();  //make sure compiler does not optimize us out 
        // int huge_stack_array[4096] = {1,2,3};
        printf("\nhello, im the beginning of tid:%u stack > %p <",(unsigned int)pthread_self(), &stack_start);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
        int i = 0;
        pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];
        pthread_attr_t myattr;
        size_t stacksize;
        pthread_attr_init(&myattr);
        pthread_attr_getstacksize(&myattr,&stacksize);
        printf("\n Initial Stack size : %d \n",stacksize);
        stacksize = 1024*16;
        if (pthread_attr_setstacksize(&myattr,stacksize)) goto failed;
        printf("\n Stack size now : %d \n",stacksize);
        for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++){
                pthread_create(&threads[i],&myattr,&mythread,(void*)i);
        }
#if 1
        for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++){
                pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
        }
#endif

        stacksize = 1024*28;
        if (pthread_attr_setstacksize(&myattr,stacksize)) goto failed;
        printf("\n Stack size now : %d \n",stacksize);
        for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++){
                pthread_create(&threads[i],&myattr,&mythread,(void*)i);
        }
#if 1
        for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++){
                pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
        }
#endif
        pthread_attr_destroy(&myattr);
        printf("\n Main tid : %u \n",(unsigned int)pthread_self());
        pthread_exit(NULL);

        failed: 
                printf("Can't set stacksize - is it multiplication of PAGE_SIZE, and >16384?\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
 $ gcc -pthread  test.c -o test && ./test

 Initial Stack size : 8388608 

 Stack size now : 16384 

hello, im the beginning of tid:3078323008 stack > 0xb77b735f <
hello, im the beginning of tid:3078306624 stack > 0xb77b335f <
 Stack size now : 28672 

hello, im the beginning of tid:3078290240 stack > 0xb77af35f <
hello, im the beginning of tid:3078261568 stack > 0xb77a835f <
 Main tid : 3076368064
```

Now, calc goes to work:

```
$ calc
; 0xb77b735f-0xb77b335f
    16384
; 0xb77af35f-0xb77a835f
    28672
```

Oh and yes, if You create int huge_array[4096] on first thread stack it segfaults, whereas works as intended on second one.